# Bash script for GDB

Tags: bash, mpi

I have an script that I used for debugging with GDB where I set breakpoints before execution:

```
#!/bin/bash

bps=( 'fer_couple.c:50' ) 


# BREAKPOINTS
for i in ${bps[@]}
do
exopt="$exopt -ex 'break $i' "
done

echo $exopt
gdbcomm="gdb $exopt --args  ../../fermi fuel_1.fer -c couple.dat"
echo $gdbcomm

mpirun -np 1 xterm -e $gdbcomm : -np 1 xterm -e gdb control
```

the problem is that when I run this I have the error in GDB:

```
Undefined command: "".  Try "help"
```

But as you see in the last `echo` if you type the command manually:

```
 gdb -ex 'break fer_couple.c:50' --args ../../fermi fuel_1.fer -c couple.dat
```

I don't have that problem. Probably I am doing something wrong with the bash variables. Thank you.

Comment: You script print value of variables `exopt` and `gdbcomm`. It prints the correct values?

Comment: Yes, it prints the correct values. But one thing is stdout and other is the value of the variable and what GDB interpret from it. Any idea ?

Comment: I think you must instead of `mpirun -np 1 xterm -e $gdbcomm : -np 1 xterm -e gdb control` use only `mpirun -np 1 xterm -e $gdbcomm`. Or i misunderstand something?

Comment: I want to have `mpirun -np 1 xterm -e gdb -ex 'break fer_couple.c:50' --args ../../fermi fuel_1.fer -c couple.dat : -np 1 xterm -e gdb control`

Comment: I think that the problem is that variable `exopt` does not inited. Try on first iteration `for` loop use `exopt="$-ex 'break $i' "` and at other iterations `exopt="$exopt -ex 'break $i' "`.

Comment: The problem is the same if you do `a="-ex 'break fer_couple.c:50'"` and `gdb $a` you get `Undefined command: "".  Try "help"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have added `"` to  `$gdbcomm` and It worked

```
#!/bin/bash

bps=( 'fer_couple.c:50' ) 

# BREAKPOINTS
for i in ${bps[@]}
do
  exopt="$exopt -ex 'break $i' "
done

gdbcomm="gdb $exopt --args  ../../fermi fuel_1.fer -c couple.dat"

mpirun -np 1 xterm -e "$gdbcomm" : -np 1 xterm -e gdb control
```

Other option that it works and likes me more is to use `eval`(http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/eval/):

```
eval mpirun -np 1 xterm -e gdb $exopt --args  ../../fermi fuel_1.fer -c couple.dat : -np 1 xterm -e gdb control
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things standout, mainly the quoting (lackof) and how `gdb` is executed.

```
for i in "${bps[@]}"
do
    exopt="$exopt -ex 'break $i' "
done
```

Since you are using an array double-quote it to avoid re-splitting elements. With the `gdb` command itself it's probably better to use a sub-shell, for example:

```
gdbcomm=$(gdb "$exopt" --args  ../../fermi fuel_1.fer -c couple.dat)
```

Also double-quote the `$exopt` variable, since that is where the command currently breaks. You can check the syntax of your script through http://shellcheck.net for similar errors/warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug the Bash script also.Use this option

```
set -x          # activate debugging from here
w
set +x          # stop debugging from here
```

Add this in the 2nd line

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x  # activate debugging from here
bps=( 'fer_couple.c:50' ) 


# BREAKPOINTS
for i in ${bps[@]}
do
exopt="$exopt -ex 'break $i' "
done

echo $exopt
gdbcomm="gdb $exopt --args  ../../fermi fuel_1.fer -c couple.dat"
echo $gdbcomm

mpirun -np 1 xterm -e $gdbcomm : -np 1 xterm -e gdb control

set +x  # stop debugging from here
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce problem that you get. For solving it at the end of script instead of

`mpirun -np 1 xterm -e $gdbcomm : -np 1 xterm -e gdb control`

use

`tail_comm=" : -np 1 gdb control"
 xterm -e "$gdbcomm $tail_comm"`

I am not sure, but it seems that the problem was that the variable `gdbcomm` is string with spaces.